# How to create custom Global System-wide variables like $Home in Powershell and assign persistent value to it?

Tags: command-line, powershell, environment-variables, persistent, global

I am just starting to learn Powershell and already one thing started bugging me.

The undesirably & unfairly confusing discrimination between `$env:Home` and `$HOME`. Where `$HOME` can be autocompleted by just typing `$hom` > <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but for it's counterpart we need to type `$env:Ho` > <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I got the idea that `$HOME` is some type of Global variable, which is persistent even after system reboot, in any Powershell session.

So the question: How do I create such persistent and global variables and assign values from either command-output or environment variable output or direct path of directory/file to it?

Comment: the only way that i can think of - while excluding the `$env:*` stuff as you seem to require - is to add the info to the appropriate powershell profile file.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish using these variables?

Comment: Powershell has a lot of [Automatic variables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#home) and `$Home` is one of them. They may or may not have anything to do with what is stored in your environment variables. If you want to create environment variables that can be processed globally, use `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("YourNewVariableName", "TheStringValueForThisVariable", [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)`

Comment: No, actually, I am asking how to create such Automatic Variables, which are available in whole Powershell system globally, means doesn't matter where I start Powershell, can you point a guide to create such automatic variables and maybe insert some modified environment variable-value to it ?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, `$home` is a global variable in powershell. These are different from environment variables. Good news is you can create your own.

One way to accomplish what you want is to edit your Powershell profile(@Lee_Dailey mentioned this in a comment).

1. First find the `profile.ps1` file you want to apply this to.
   There are a few of these in different locations, and each corresponds to different users/permissions. You can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7.3) to choose which one you want to apply it to. I will use `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1`.
2. Add your variables as follows:

```
$docs = "C:\Users\<username>\Documents"
# ^^^         ^^^
# name       value
```

3. Restart powershell
4. You can now use it with the same functionality as `$home`.

```
cd $docs
```